# How to interact with standard Opensea contract via my own smartcontract?

Tags: solidity

I am writing my smart contract and one of its functions should be the function of buying nft directly from open sea. Is it possible to interact with an open-sea contract directly from my personal solidity contract? If this is not possible, then how can it be properly implemented?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, OpenSea contracts only manage the NFTs collection contracts published by other users, so you can't "directly" buy from OpeanSea's contract, but what you can do is interact directly with the collection's contract.

> To find the collection's contract address on OpenSea, for example on an NFT's page, under Details, there is a blue hyperlinked value labeled "Contract Address". If you click on this, it will take you to the contract's address on Etherscan; at the top-left of that page, there should be an icon labeled "Contract", and to the right, a long string of letters and numbers. This is the address of the contract that created your NFT.
> Click on the "copy" icon to the right of the address, and you'll have it on your clipboard.

From: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/113932/where-to-find-the-address-of-the-nft-contract-i-created-on-opensea